# Ревью кода FreeRadius

Tags: python, python-2.x, инспекция-кода

Есть замечательный продукт FreeRadius. Использую два rlm(python, dhcp). В этом продукте чистый api_dhcp, всю логику задаешь на основании [rfc-2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) и немного своей.

Хотел бы получить критику и пожелания к [коду](http://pastebin.com/9Zbf1TXp), что на ваш взгляд переделать или исправить, не вдаваясь в глубокие подробности:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys
import time
import sqlalchemy
from decorator import decorator
import radiusd
import bitstring
import ipaddress
from _sql import *
from _params import *


engine = None
RADIUS_TYPE_MAP = (
    (re.compile('^"(.*)"$'), lambda m: m.group(1)),
    (re.compile('^(-?\d+)$'), lambda m: int(m.group(1))),)


def radius_value(value_string):
    if type(value_string) in (str, unicode):
        for regexp, processor in RADIUS_TYPE_MAP:
            m = regexp.match(value_string)
            if m is not None:
                return processor(m)
    return value_string


@decorator
def radius_function(f, params):
    data = dict()
    for name, value in params:
        data[name] = radius_value(value)
    try:
        data = f(data)
    except:
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_FAIL
    if type(data) is tuple:
        res = (data[0],) + tuple(map(lambda d: tuple(d.iteritems()), data[1:]))
    else:
        res = data
    return res


@radius_function
def attibutes(p):
    return p


def log(level, s):
    radiusd.radlog(level, s)


def instantiate(p):
    global engine
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root:dfdfd@localhost:3306/UTM5',pool_size=100, max_overflow=10)
    log(radiusd.L_INFO, 'db connection: ' + str(engine))


def authorize(p):
    print "*** authorize ***"
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK


def accounting(p):
    print "*** accounting ***"
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK


def pre_proxy(p):
    print "*** pre_proxy ***"
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK


def post_proxy(p):
    print "*** post_proxy ***"
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK

def answer(venid,ans):
    if venid == 'synet':
        return synet,ans
    else:
        return ans


def extract(nets):
    mask = ('DHCP-Subnet-Mask', nets['mask'])
    router = ('DHCP-Router-Address', nets['gw'])
    yiaddr = ('DHCP-Your-IP-Address', nets['ip'])
    return (mask, router, yiaddr)


def extract2(p):
    if ('DHCP-Relay-Remote-Id' in p) and ('DHCP-Relay-Circuit-Id' in p):
        vlan = bitstring.BitArray(p.get('DHCP-Relay-Circuit-Id', None))[16:-16].int
        port = bitstring.BitArray(p.get('DHCP-Relay-Circuit-Id', None))[40:].int
        switch = bitstring.BitArray(p.get('DHCP-Relay-Remote-Id', None))[16:].bytes
        return (vlan, port, switch)
    else:
        vlan = 0
        port = 0
        switch = ''
        return (vlan,port,switch)


def post_auth(p):
    try:
        dbHandle = engine.connect()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError, e:
        log(radiusd.L_ERR, str(e))
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_FAIL

    t = int(time.time())
    p = attibutes(p)
    msgtype = p.get('DHCP-Message-Type', None)
    chaddr = p.get('DHCP-Client-Hardware-Address', None)
    venid = p.get('DHCP-Vendor-Class-Identifier', None)
    xid = '%x' %int(p.get('DHCP-Transaction-Id', None))
    cid = p.get('DHCP-Client-Identifier',None)
    rip = p.get('DHCP-Requested-IP-Address', None) if p.get('DHCP-Requested-IP-Address', None) != '0.0.0.0' else None
    sid = p.get('DHCP-DHCP-Server-Identifier', None) if p.get('DHCP-DHCP-Server-Identifier', None) != '0.0.0.0' else None
    cip = p.get('DHCP-Client-IP-Address', None) if p.get('DHCP-Client-IP-Address', None) != '0.0.0.0' else None


    if msgtype == "DHCP-Discover":
        (vlan, port, switch) = extract2(p);
        res = dbHandle.execute(select_mac.format(switch,chaddr)).fetchall()
        if res:
            if len(res) == 1:
                nets = [n for n in res][0]
                ipnet = ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(nets['ip'])) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(nets['net']+'/'+nets['mask']))
                if ipnet == True:
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Discover:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'ok'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Discover",chaddr,venid,"ok",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                    (mask, router, yiaddr) = extract(nets)
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Offer:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'ok'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Offer",chaddr,venid,"ok",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                    return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (ns1,ns2,ntp,mask,router,lease,serverid,domain,yiaddr,answer(venid,msgoffer)),())
                else:
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Discover:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'error_nets'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Discover",chaddr,venid,"error_nets",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP
            else:
                log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Discover:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,0,'duble_mac'))
                dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Discover",chaddr,venid,"duble_mac",switch,port,vlan,""))
                return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP
        else:
            log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Discover:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,0,'free_res_82'))
            dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Discover",chaddr,venid,"free_res_82",switch,port,vlan,""))
            return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP


    elif msgtype == "DHCP-Request":
        if sid and not cip: #SELECTING
            (vlan, port, switch) = extract2(p);
            log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Request:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'ok_sel'))                                              
            dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Request",chaddr,venid,"ok_sel",switch,port,vlan,rip))
            res = dbHandle.execute(select_ip.format(switch,rip)).fetchall()
            if res:
                if len(res) == 1:
                    nets = [n for n in res][0]
                    ipnet = ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(nets['ip'])) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(nets['net']+'/'+nets['mask']))
                    if ipnet == True:
                        (mask, router, yiaddr) = extract(nets)
                        log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Ask:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'ok_sel'))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Ask",chaddr,venid,"ok_sel",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_lease.format(t,t+lease_time,xid,nets['ip'],chaddr,switch,port,'active'))
                        return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (ns1,ns2,ntp,mask,router,lease,serverid,domain,yiaddr,answer(venid,msgask)),())
                    else:
                        log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_error_nets_sel'))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_error_nets_sel",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND
                else:
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_duble_mac_sel'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_duble_mac_sel",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND
            else:
                log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_res_82_sel'))
                dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_res_82_sel",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND


        elif not sid and not cip and rip: #INIT-REBOOT
            (vlan, port, switch) = extract2(p);
            log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Request:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'ok_init'))
            dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Request",chaddr,venid,"ok_init",switch,port,vlan,rip))
            res = dbHandle.execute(select_ip.format(switch,rip)).fetchall()
            if res:
                if len(res) == 1:
                    nets = [n for n in res][0]
                    ipnet = ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(nets['ip'])) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(nets['net']+'/'+nets['mask']))
                    if ipnet == True:
                        (mask, router, yiaddr) = extract(nets)
                        log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Ask:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'ok_init'))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Ask",chaddr,venid,"ok_init",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_lease.format(lease_time,xid,nets['ip'],chaddr,switch,port,'active'))
                        return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (ns1,ns2,ntp,mask,router,lease,serverid,domain,yiaddr,answer(venid,msgask)),())
                    else:
                        log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_error_nets_init'))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_error_nets_init",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND
                else:
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_duble_mac_init'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_duble_mac_init",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND
            else:
                log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,0,'nak_res_82_init'))
                dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_res_82_init",switch,port,vlan,rip))
                return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND


        elif not sid and cip and not rip: #RENEWING or REBINDING
            res = dbHandle.execute(select_lease.format(t,xid,cip,chaddr)).fetchall()
            (vlan, port, switch) = extract2(p);
            log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Request:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'ok_renew'))
            dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Request",chaddr,venid,"ok_renew",switch,port,vlan,cip))
            if res:
                res2 = dbHandle.execute(select_ip.format(res[0]['switch'],cip)).fetchall()
                if len(res2) == 1:
                    nets = [n for n in res2][0]
                    ipnet = ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(nets['ip'])) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(nets['net']+'/'+nets['mask']))
                    if ipnet == True:
                        (mask, router, yiaddr) = extract(nets)
                        log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-Ask:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,nets['ip'],'ok_renew'))
                        dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-Ask",chaddr,venid,"ok_renew",switch,port,vlan,nets['ip']))
                        dbHandle.execute(update_lease.format(t,t+lease_time,res[0]['id']))
                        return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (ns1,ns2,ntp,mask,router,lease,serverid,domain,yiaddr,answer(venid,msgask)),())
                else:
                    log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,rip,'nak_duble_mac_renew'))
                    dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_duble_mac_renew",switch,port,vlan,cip))
                    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND
            else:
                log(radiusd.L_INFO, dhcp_log.format('DHCP-NAK:',xid,switch,port,vlan,chaddr,venid,0,'nak_res_82_renew'))
                dbHandle.execute(insert_log.format(t,xid,"DHCP-NAK",chaddr,venid,"nak_res_82_renew",switch,port,vlan,cip))
        else:
            log(radiusd.L_INFO, 'DHCP-Request: not_if')
            return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP


    elif msgtype == "DHCP-Release":
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP


    elif msgtype == "DHCP-Inform":
        return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (msgask,),())


    elif msgtype == "DHCP-Decline":
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP

def recv_coa(p):
    print "*** recv_coa ***"
    print p
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK


def send_coa(p):
    print "*** send_coa ***"
    print p
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK


def detach(_p):
    print "*** detach ***"
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
```

Comment: Разбейте post_auth на функции. Условные операторы 5-го уровня вложенности затрудняют читаемость. Вы сами через неделю ничего в этом коде не поймете.

Answer (score 1):

Импорт такого вида from _sql import * не рекомендуется. Просто импортируй модуль вот так: import _sql или при использовании from указывай какие конкретно ты переменные импортируешь.